# Unwanted destruction in C++

Tags: c++, class, object, memory-management, constructor

I have the following code:

```
class A;
typedef map<string, A*> AMap;
AMap _amap;
```

When I try to allocate a new A and save it to map:

```
A a = A(str);
_amap[str] = &a;
```

then it will call `A`'s destructor before my program ended. (I have a static member for A to count object, which returns zero when I want to check how many objects there are)

However, when I try:

```
_amap[str] = new A(str);
```

everything works fine, but the destructor didn't be called. Why is that?

What is the difference between these two approaches?

Thanks.

**Update**

The reason why I use `A*` instead of `A` is that I have another `AList`, which is a vector, will store the same object. I use pointer because I don't want to waste memory.

Comment: The former adds the address of an automatic variable the latter a dynamically allocated variable. **You** allocated it dynamically. That means either you manage that with a smart pointer that knows how to properly cleanup or take up the responsibility to do it yourself, *just like you did to allocate it*.

Comment: @WhozCraig does that explain why the destructor is called in the first case? Because I cannot see why.

Comment: The word *automatic* is imperative to that. What you're left with, whether you knew it or not, was a map with a *dangling pointer*. I.e. the pointer in the map is still there, but the object is destroyed as soon as `a` leaves automatic scope ( the surrounding `{... }` ). And in case you didn't know, even *evaluating*, much less *dereferencing* a dangling pointer invokes undefined behavior. Both answers below are accurate in how to manage this, and are worthy of up-ticks. Read them carefully.

Comment: Any reason you're not using a `map<string, A>`? Why the pointer?

Comment: The reason why I use `A*` instead of `A` is that I have another `AList`, which is a vector, will store the same object. I use pointer because I don't want to waste memory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the second case the destructor is not called because you probably never `delete` the `A` object that you allocated on the heap.

Consider instead using the following typedef:

```
typedef map<string, unique_ptr<A>> AMap;
```

Then, create objects using `std::make_unique`:

```
_amap[str] = make_unique<A>(str);
```

(Or, prior to C++14: `_amap[str] = unique_ptr<A>(new A(str));`)

The `std::unique_ptr` destructor will ensure that the heap-allocated object is deleted, but note that this means when `_amap` is destroyed, all of the `A` objects in the map will be too!

If you have other code that might need pointers to these objects beyond the lifetime of `_amap` then consider instead using `shared_ptr<A>` (and `make_shared<A>`).  These are *shared ownership* smart pointers that will only delete the object when *all* `shared_ptr<A>` instances are destroyed.

On the other hand, if you simply need the `A` objects to exist *somewhere* then they can live in the map:

```
typedef map<string, A> AMap;
```

And later:

```
_amap.emplace(make_pair(str, A(str)));
```

Answer (score 3):

In the first approach you are storing the address of an automatic ("stack allocated") variable which is not a good idea unless you know that the map itself will not be used after its values  go out of scope.

In the second approach you call `new` but never `delete`, which is of course a resource leak.

Instead of these two, you should either store instances of `A` directly in the map without pointers, or if you need pointers for polymorphism, store smart pointers so the destruction of the values will occur during the destruction of the map.